Can't open the extracted file using Laravel ZipArchive
In the system, there's a export capability where the user can export multiple files. We decided to put all the multiple files into zip folder.
We used the ZipArchive, so far what we have: export the multiple files and manage to put it in the zip folder but when we clicked the zip folder it gives us an error

Controller:
        $vendors                            = explode(',', $data['id']);

    foreach ($vendors as $v => $vendor) {
        # code...
        $array['id']                    = $vendor;
        $array['start_date']            = $data['start_date'];
        // $array['start_date']            = $new_start_date;
        // $array['end_date']              = $end_date;
        $array['end_date']              = date('Y-m-t',strtotime($data['start_date']));
        $purchases                      = StatementOfAccountModel::getSoaSubsidiaryLedgerPurchasesDetailsAll($array);
        $purchase_details               = StatementOfAccountsItemsController::getSoaPurchaseDetails($purchases);

        $payments                       = StatementOfAccountModel::getSoaSubsidiaryLedgerPaymentsDetailsAll($array);
        $payment_details                = StatementOfAccountsItemsController::getSoaPaymentsDetails($payments);

        // $purchase_details               = [];
        // $payment_details                = [];

        $statement_details              = collect(array_merge($purchase_details,$payment_details))->sortBy('date');
        $get_header_color               = ui_pdf($this->function);

        $pdf                            = new PDF();

        // $pdf                            = new Pdf('wkhtmltopdf');
        // $pdf->setOption('timeout', 300); // Increase timeout to 120 seconds

        $data = array(
            'vendor'                    => GlobalModel::getSingleDataTable('vendors',$vendor)->name,
            'statement_details'         => $statement_details,
            'header_color'              => $get_header_color['color'],
            'paper_orientation'         => $get_header_color['paper_orientation'],
            'font_style'                => $get_header_color['font_style'],
            'font_size'                 => $get_header_color['font_size'],
            'module'                    => 'Vendor Transaction History'
        );

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.statement-of-accounts.export.export-vendor-pdf', $data);

        $filename = "Association-Dues_Statement-of-Account-".$v.".pdf";
        $temp = $pdf->download($filename);
        Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, $temp);
        unset($pdf);
    }

    // CREATE ZIP & DELETE FILES
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if (true === ($zip->open('Association-Dues_Statement-of-Accounts.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE))) {
        foreach (Storage::allFiles('public') as $file) {
            $filenames[] = $file;
            $name = basename($file);
            if ($name !== '.gitignore') {   
                $zip->addFile(public_path("storage/" . $name), $name);
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
        // foreach (Storage::allFiles('public') as $file) {
        //     $name = basename($file);
        //     if ($name !== '.gitignore') {
        //         File::delete(public_path('storage/'.$name), $name);
        //     }
        // }
    }

    return response()->download(public_path('Association-Dues_Statement-of-Accounts.zip'), 'Association-Dues_Statement-of-Accounts.zip')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

View
if ( $('#export-pdf-button').length > 0 ) {
$('#export-pdf-button').click(function(e){
    var start_date              = $('input[name="start_date"]').val();
    var vendor_id       = [];
    var form = this;  
    var rows_selected = $('#get-vendors-export').DataTable().column(2).checkboxes.selected();
    $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
        vendor_id.push(rowId)
    }); 
    var formData = '&id='+vendor_id+'&start_date='+start_date;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })
    $.ajax({
        url: '/reports/vendor-transaction-history/exportVendorsPDF',
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.general-filter-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.loader').show();
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = '<span class="loading-animation">LOADING...</span>';
            swal({
                content: span,
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: false,
                closeOnClickOutside: false
            });
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                var binaryData = [];
                binaryData.push(response);
                 var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))
                link.download = 'asdasda.zip';
                link.click();
                sweet_success();
            }else{
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
             $('.general-filter-button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
    // $('#export-pdf-button').attr('href', '<?php //echo URL::to('/reports/vendor-transaction-history/exportVendorsPDF'); ?>/'+vendor_id+'/'+start_date);
    // e.preventDefault();
    // return false;
});

}
What is causing this error?
Edited
I drag the zip folder to my text editor, below is the result.


Open the zip file in a text editor to check the contents.

I drag the zip file into my text editor, what should I check?

And beware that it won't work if 2 users do the export at the same time, You should use a temporary file with a unique name.

What do you see at the beginning?

I edited my post, I added the screenshot of the beginning of the zip folder

So your file starts with a space followed by a P? That's strange. Anyway it's not a valid zip file indeed, because a zip starts with PK.

Sorry where can I find that?

Oh actually it starts with a space followed by PK. It means that you have an extra space at the beginning. Check your PHP scripts, you probably have a space somewhere that you should remove.

PHP scripts? is it the creating of file or the zip?

Does it work if you remove the leading 20 from the file? If yes there may be a stray space in one of your source files e.g. before a <?php

It actually works when I remove the 20 beside of 50, I already check there's no space before the <?php in my controller

There can be a space in any included file, before <?php or after ?>.

I changed my code, i used this $('#export-pdf-button').attr('href', '/'+vendor_id+'/'+start_date). Is this the reason?
